# What are benefits of standalone ActionCable server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

Rails guide describes the opportunity to run ActionCable standalone server with regular Rails app. But I want to understand the benefits of such approach in context of running Rails app in docker containers. Why it may be useful for scaling for example?

Answer (score 5):

The main benefit is separation of concerns and redundancy. Having a standalone ActionCable server allows you to scale that completely independently of your Rails server.

For example, let's you have a memory-leak issue in your ActionCable code and it is deployed in the same container as the Rails server. It will eventually bring the whole application down. If it is separated though, the Rails server will still be running while you can fix the memory issue and redeploy the ActionCable server.

It's better to think of the ActionCable server as a WebSocket server, as that's what it really is. In theory this separation of concerns allows you to relatively quickly change the framework for your WebSocket server, maybe something written in Go. In reality though ActionCable is heavily integrated with Rails code so it's not that straight-forward, but that is one of the main ideas behind it.

In terms of redundancy, let's say you get 10x the amount of HTTP requests compared to WS requests (even though they are not exactly comparable). If the server is separated in a container, we might not want to scale the web Rails server and ActionCable server at the same rate. This allows us to let's say have 6 containers of Rails servers, while only 2 containers of ActionCable servers, thus saving you resources.